# What techniques are used in these computations of partition functions?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics

I am reading ["Quiver W-algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08533v3) and I have some questions about their computations of partition functions. How to obtain (3.21)

> $$\begin{multline}
>   Z_{\mathsf{T}}(t) = \sum_{\mathcal{X} \in \mathfrak{M}^{\mathsf{T}}} \exp\left( - \sum_{ (x_L,x_R)\in \mathcal{X}
>         \times \mathcal{X}} \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}
>     \frac{1 - q_1^{p}}{1 - q_2^{-p}} (c^{+}_{\mathsf{i}(x_L), \mathsf{i}(x_R)})^{[p]} x_L^{-p} x_R^{p}
>     \right) \\\times 
> \exp\left( \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}  \left( - \frac {\kappa_{\mathsf{i}(x)}} 2 ( \log_{q_2} x -1) \log_{q_2} x+  \log \mathfrak{q}_{\mathsf{i}(x)} \log_{q_2} \frac{x}{\mathring{x}} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} (1
>   -q_1^{p}) t_{\mathsf{i}(x),p} x^{p} \right) \right)
> \end{multline}\tag{3.21}$$

from (2.11)?

> $$\begin{multline}Z_{\mathsf{T}}(t)  = \sum_{\mathfrak{M}^{\mathsf{T}}} \mathfrak{q}^{\gamma} \exp{\left(\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p} \operatorname{ch}_{\mathsf{T}}
>       (T^{\vee}_{\mathfrak{M}^{\mathsf{T}}} \mathfrak{M} )^{[p]} \right)} \\
> \times\prod_{i
>         \in \Gamma_0} \operatorname{ch}_{\mathsf{T}} [\det i^*_{\mathsf{T}} \hat{\mathbf{Y}}]^{\kappa_i} \exp{\left( \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} t_{i,p} \operatorname{ch}_{\mathsf{T}}
>         (i^{*}_{\mathsf{T}}\mathbf{Y}_{i})^{[p]}\right)}\end{multline}\tag{2.11}$$

Similarly, do the formulas (3.28)-(3.31) quoted below follow from (3.23)?

> $$\begin{multline}
>   Z_{\mathsf{T}}(t) = \sum_{\mathcal{X} \in \mathfrak{M}^{\mathsf{T}}} \exp\left(  \sum_{ (x_L \succ x_R) \in \Lambda^2\mathcal{X}
>    } -(c_{\mathsf{i}(x_R),\mathsf{i}(x_L)}^{+})^{[0]}\beta  \log\frac{x_{R}}{ x_L} -\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}
>     \frac{1 - q_1^{p}}{1 - q_2^{-p}} (c_{\mathsf{i}(x_L), \mathsf{i}(x_R)})^{[p]} \frac{ x_R^{p}}{{x_L}^{p}}
>     \right) \\\times 
> \exp \left( \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left( - \frac {\kappa_{\mathsf{i}(x)}} 2 (
>     \log_{q_2} x -1) \log_{q_2} x +  \log \mathfrak{q}_{\mathsf{i}(x)}  \log_{q_2} \frac{x}{\mathring{x}} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} (1
>   -q_1^{p}) t_{\mathsf{i}(x),p} x^{p}  \right) \right)
> \end{multline}\tag{3.23}$$
>
> ...
>
> $$S_{i,x} =            :  \exp\big(  \sum_{p > 0 } s_{i,-p} x^{p} + s_{i,0} \log x + \tilde s_{i,0} +
>   \sum_{p > 0 } s_{i,p} x^{-p}\big):\tag{3.28}$$
>
> Here  the *free field modes* or *oscillators* are
>
> $$    s_{i,-p} \stackrel{p>0}{=} ( 1- q_1^{p}) t_{i,p}, \qquad  s_{i,0} =
>     t_{i,0}, \quad 
>     s_{i, p} \stackrel{p>0}{=} -\frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{1 - q_2^{-p}} c_{ij}^{[p]} \partial_{j,p}\tag{3.29}$$
>
> with commutation relations
>
> $$[ s_{i,p}, s_{j,p'}] =- \delta_{p+p',0}\frac{1}{p} \frac{1 - q_1^p}{1 -
>    q_2^{-p}} c_{ij}^{[p]}, \qquad p > 0\tag{3.30}$$
>
> The conjugate *zero mode* $\tilde s_{i,0}$ satisfies
>
> $$[ \tilde s_{i,0} , s_{j,p}] = -\beta  \delta_{0,p} c_{ij}^{[0]}\tag{3.31}$$

These formulas are very complicated.

Supplementing an answer with references where I can further study the techniques of these computations would be appreciated.

Comment: A note for the future: don't include images of anything that can be typed in a post. You should always retype the text in a quote block instead. I've included the equations for you here; if you want to include the rest of the text from your images, you're welcome to edit it in, just no pictures.